# Something like OpenCart for Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, e-commerce, opencart, shopping-cart

I've searched so far many times for this question but unfortunately without any result.
This is my question: Is there any open source shopping cart solution (e-commerce system) for javaEE (java based)? I mean something like **OpenCart**.

I appreciate your comments.

Comment: I don't know the reason of down-vote :)

Comment: Why do you ask for a Java EE solution like OpenCart - OpenCart is incredibly fast out of box, the MVC and PHP make it easily scalable and cheap. Java is more enterprise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Broadleaf Commerce is open source based on Spring and Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Apache OFBiz (The Apache Open For Business Project) . The development community is quite helpful. The live demo is also available for more details visit  [ofbiz](http://ofbiz.apache.org/) . There is also BigFish Open source E-commerce which is based on ofbiz platform.